# How to query 2 table but there is possibility of one of the row is empty?

Tags: sql

My goal is to separate `UserDetails` into 2 tables, and query it with one SQL statement.

Table `user_detail`

```
id | user | name
```

Table `user_subscribe`

```
id | user | friendIds | channelIds
```

There is a possibility that either `user_detail` or `user_subscribe` is empty. This is the solution I come up with:

```
SELECT 
    user_detail.user, user_detail.name, 
    user_subscribe.friendIds, user_subscribe.channelIds 
FROM 
    user_detail, user_subscribe 
WHERE 
    user_detail.user = #{username} 
    AND user_detail.user = #{username}
```

The above SQL statement works if there is a row with column `user` with `#{username}` both in table `user_detail` and `user_subscribe`.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s well noted. I use `LEFT JOIN`, `ON`, and `WHERE`. It works and easier to read.

Comment: I double check, and it does not work if the LEFT JOIN table is empty, which in this case we don't know which table is empty, so I am forced to set the rules on the server side instead of relying on sql statement. I found out about `FULL JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN` from w3school, it seems it is what I need but as per your reference says, it is discontinued since 2012, I will for another solution. Anyway, thank you I will follow your reference in writing SQL statement.

Comment: You're mixing something up - the `*=` and `=*` "join" syntax was discontinued with SQL Server 2012 - but `FULL (OUTER) JOIN`  is still absolutely valid !

Comment: well noted. I tried to use `FULL JOIN`, `FULL OUTER JOIN` with MyBatis. It throws `BadSqlGrammarExeption`. I assuming `FULL JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN` is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1):

You could use left join

```
 SELECT 
    user_detail.user, user_detail.name, 
    user_subscribe.friendIds, user_subscribe.channelIds 
FROM 
    user_detail
    LEFT JOIN  user_subscribe  ON user_detail.user = #{username} 
    AND user_detail.user =  user_detail.user
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you use `ON user_detail.user = #{username}` instead of `WHERE user_detail.user=#{username}`?

Comment: I double checked and my assumption was correct. If you use `ON user_detail.user=#{username}`, potentially it will return more than 1 row.

Comment: if you want obtain at least on row  if the join condition fails you need  left join  ... and assign  user_detail.user = #{username} AND user_detail.user =  user_detail.user  OR user_detail.user = #{username}  AND  user_detail.user =#{username} is the same  ..  the explicit join sintax  allow LEFT JOIN and the sintax  is based on  the ON clause  .. with where clause you can't use lleft join  ...the use of where clause automatically implies a INNER JOIN